# In code_subject there are values in the following formats string1#string2#integer#string3. How to extract integer?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the table code_subject there is a row with a following format string1#string2#integer#string3. How to extract a number (integer) from it?

IS IT LIKE THAT?:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('integer') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM code_subject

Comment: Try REGEXP_SUBSTR:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm

Comment: IS IT LIKE THAT?:
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('integer') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
  FROM code_subject

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using regexp_replace:

```
select regexp_replace('stringA#stringB#1234#stringC', '[^0-9]', '') 
from dual;
```

Another possibility is:

```
select substr('string1#string2#1234#string3', instr('string1#string2#1234#string3', '#', 1, 2) + 1,
 instr('string1#string2#1234#string3', '#', 1, 3) - instr('string1#string2#1234#string3', '#', 1, 2) - 1) 
from dual;
```